# Inheriting member function pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I saw this code online and I was wondering how it is implemented.  Since member function pointers cannot be assigned to a base class's member function pointers I am curious where the pointers for the derived class's member functions are being stored and how.

This is the header file with the test declarations

```
#ifndef TestStudent_h
#define TestStudent_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Note 1
#include "TestCase.h"
#include "TestSuite.h"
#include "TestCaller.h"
#include "TestRunner.h"

#include "Student.h"

class StudentTestCase : public TestCase { // Note 2 
public:
  // constructor - Note 3
  StudentTestCase(std::string name) : TestCase(name) {}

  // method to test the constructor
  void testConstructor();

  // method to test the assigning and retrieval of grades
  void testAssignAndRetrieveGrades();

  // method to create a suite of tests
  static Test *suite ();
};
#endif
```

And this is the implementation of the function that adds the member functions to some sort of list

```
// method to create a suite of tests - Note 7
Test *StudentTestCase::suite () {
  TestSuite *testSuite = new TestSuite ("StudentTestCase");

  // add the tests
  testSuite->addTest (new TestCaller  
      ("testConstructor", &StudentTestCase::testConstructor));
  testSuite->addTest (new TestCaller  
      ("testAssignAndRetrieveGrades", 
       &StudentTestCase::testAssignAndRetrieveGrades));
  return testSuite;
}
```

I was wondering what data type the member functions are being stored in since they cannot be stored in any function pointer type known to the base class..  Also the location where they are stored will have to know the type of the class under which these are defined since whatever entity that calls these objects will need to "link" these functions with objects of that type too right?  Specifically in this function how will `TestCaller` know how to call the member functions that were added to it?

Comment: @n.m. But they need to be stored somewhere ?

Comment: The base class is not involved, TestSuite is.

Comment: Sorry I think I don't understand what you are asking. Member functions are not "stored" anywhere, they just are. Member function pointers are stored in their soecialized data types. They are primitive data types without any structure.

Comment: @kfsone then how will TestSuite know how to call those functions? They will have to be linked with an object of type `StudentTestCase` right?

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote?

Comment: @n.m. Is the question more clear now?

Comment: You may need to show some part of the definition of TestCaller.

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want to know how the compiler implements pointers to member functions?

Comment: @n.m. He's unsure how something that knows nothing about "StudentTestCase" can store and invoke a member function pointer, since he's expecting it will need to have a prototype like `TestCaller(const char*, void StudentTestCase::*fn (void))` and he doesn't understand how it gets the right prototype. I'm guessing templates.

Comment: @n.m. I am wondering how this could possibly work without the TestSuite knowing where this function came from

Comment: OK got it now. What is the prototype for addTest and the TestCaller constructor?

Comment: I am not sure... That is why I asked. I was hoping to get some answers giving me some options of what it might be!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `TestCaller` has a constructor that looks like

```
template<class Callee>
TestCaller(
    const std::string &description, 
    void (Callee::*test_method)());
```

Note that:

1. Within the body of this constructor (i.e., when it is instantiated), the type of `Callee` is known.
2. `TestCaller` itself must store `test_method` in a way that does not "know" `Callee`, since it is not itself a template class parameterized by `Callee` (and in fact, there might be more than a single `Callee`).

So this is a classic case for *type erasure*. There are many libraries that do this (e.g., [`boost::TypeErasure`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) or `boost::any`).

The idea is that `TestCaller` stores (probably indirectly) pointers to a non-template base class. There are templated versions of a derived class. Within this templated ctor, the derived class is instantiated, and an object of this type is dynamically allocated. What is stored, though is a pointer to the non-template base class.

Comment: @Curious :-) I was very happy when I saw this technique for the first time (in some serialization library).

Comment: But in the code the `new` operator is being called without a template argument.. So will this really work?

Comment: Oh no it might,  the function is added into the `TestCaller` class.  Thanks!